# django generic one-to-one relations, with cascading deletes

Tags: python, django, django-models, generic-relations

I'm trying to emulate an inheritance model using django's [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).  So far, this is what I've come up with:

```
class Base(models.Model):
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
  ... other stuff

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ("content_type", "object_id")

class SubClass1(models.Model):
  ... properties for this class

  _base = generic.GenericRelation(Base)

  @property
  def base(self):
    return self._base.all()[0]
```

From what you can see here (hopefully, at least), the `SubClass1` should have a one-to-one relationship with `Base`, which is why I went through all the work of creating that `_base` field and then covering it with the `base` property.  Having that generic relation will automagically wire up cascading deletes, which is what I want (and I have a `post-delete` signal that will wire up the delete from the other direction).

There could be any number of subclasses off of `Base`, and the thing that makes me feel gross is having to copy&paste the `_base` and its covering property.  I've also got a custom object manager that goes with this, and potentially other things that essentially should all behave the same within each subclass of `Base`.

Is there a good way to go about encapsulating this common functionality so I don't have to copy&paste it for each sub class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a `BaseSubClass`, and then inherit from that. So based on your example:

```
class BaseSubClass(models.Model):
    _base = generic.GenericRelation(Base)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @property
    def base(self):
      return self._base.all()[0]

class SubClass1(BaseSubClass):
    # fields
```

Comment: I initially did this, but didn't like the way the models framework built up the database... then while I was bulding up an example to explain why I wouldn't accept your answer I remembered about abstract base classes and added the `abstract = True` attribute in the `Meta` class, and it looks perfect!

Comment: You're right. I actually intended to add `abstract = True` but then completely forgot. I updated my answer above accordingly.